# Meteor Template - inherit or outsource events to avoid code redundancy

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a page with a bunch of image galleries. Each gallery is accessible via a menu link like this:

```
Gallery1  Gallery2  Gallery3
```

Each gallery has its own functionality but certain functions like click forward and click bardward they share.

The file structure is like this:

```
Gallery_Layout.html
Gallery_Layout.js
Gallery1.html
Gallery1.js
Gallery2.html
Gallery2.js
Gallery3.html
Gallery3.js
```

With FlowRouter each Gallery is rendered in the Layout.
At the moment said shared functions are redundant in every Galleries' js file:

Gallery1.js:

```
Template.gallery1.events({
    'click .btn-backward' (event, template) {
        // show last picture
    },
    'click .btn-forward' (event, template) {
            // show next picture
    }
});
```

Gallery2.js:

```
Template.gallery2.events({
    'click .btn-backward' (event, template) {
        // show last picture
    },
    'click .btn-forward' (event, template) {
            // show next picture
    }
});
```

And so on..

When i outsource these events to the parent Template namely Gallery_Layout.js it doesn't work.

For Helpers i know there's the global helper, is there a pendant for events?

**Question:** How can i outsource or inherit Template events and use them as reusable components?

Thanks in advance!

Muff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can use the body template:

```
Template.body.events({

});
```

Every template is loaded inside of body.

2) You can ply with selectors. Gallery is an HTML class that belongs to all galleries,

```
Template.Gallery_Layout.events({
'click .gallery' (event, instance) {

 let gallery = event.target;

 // execute code on gallery.


}

});
```